# Как можно получить модели из базы данных, в именах которых содержатся некоторые символы?

Tags: php, laravel

Как можно получить модели из базы данных, в именах которых содержатся некоторые символы?

Например, у меня есть поиск, в котором пользователь вводит название товара, а ему выводится список товаров, названия которых совпали с его поиском (не слово в слово).

Пример: Название товара в базе данных Shoes, а пользователь написал shoes, sho, oes и ему выдается этот товар

Есть ли какой-нибудь способ это сделать в методе `where` (регулярные выражения также приветствуются)?

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
Product::where('name', $name)->get() ?? [];
```

Comment: mysql like + %name, name%, %name%  или [match against](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Fulltext_Search.html) через whereRaw().. Но если товаров прям очень много то для полнотекстового поиска лучше отдельный поисковик сделать

Comment: `Product::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$name.'%')`

Comment: @RazGalstyan, оформляйте как ответ, сработало

Comment: @Alexandr_Yakovlev Ну я знаю что должно было работать.)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `laravel`, `where` может иметь и 3 параметра. Тогда второй параметр это сравнение. И оно может принять `LIKE`.

Код будет таким.

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
Product::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$name.'%')->get() ?? [];
```

Подробно можете прочитать в [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#basic-where-clauses).